# Authentication with Active Directory

Tags: iphone, authentication, active-directory

I have search for answers but i couldn't find one. If anyone could help me with it.

I'm writing an app that requires user to login. and User login details are retrieved from Organisation Active Directory.

so is there any where that i can get help from?

Thanks!

Comment: I merged your active and directory tag to the active-directory one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. Port the samba functionality from Linux (a lot of work i think)

B. Do the work in a (.NET) webservice and call it from your app.